# Max Q vs Prandtl-Meyer Fan

Tags: aerodynamics, exhaust, max-q, shockwave

Does Max Q occur before or after the [Prandtl–Meyer expansion fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prandtl%E2%80%93Meyer_expansion_fan)? The shape, nature's way of avoiding a single shock wave (per Wikipedia) is visible on the Apollo launches for example.

[image] Apollo 11, [Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_11_Launch_-_GPN-2000-000628.jpg)

Comment: I see a distinct lack of photo. [Edit] in the plain link?

Comment: Given an official photo, it shouldn't be too hard to figure out at what mission GET it was taken, and I'm fairly certain that we know the moment of Max Q with reasonable precision for all Apollo launches. Those two pieces of information would give you your answer...

Comment: Is [this is the photo](http://i.imgur.com/mWfUJJ3.jpg) you meant?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the image and hopefully to induce some activity. *Further editing* by someone "more aerodynamic" than myself may be of benefit.

Comment: Some free data for those who want to make an answer:

Apollo 11 Launch date: July 16, 1969, 13:32:00 UTC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11) 

According to https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/01launch.html, MaxQ happened at 000:01:23 GET


Unfortunately, it is not clear when the image was taken exactly - it was probably taken before 2 min and half, but we don't know if it was taken before or after 1:23 (MaxQ).

Comment: The photo description in https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_11_Launch_-_GPN-2000-000628.jpg
(which is the same on the NASA commons flickr account https://www.flickr.com/photos/nasacommons/9457415091/in/album-72157634973926806/) says: (July 16, 1969) The Apollo 11 Saturn V space vehicle climbs toward orbit after liftoff from Pad 39A at 9:32 a.m. EDT on July 16, 1969. In 2 1/2 minutes of powered flight, the S-IC booster lifts the vehicle to an altitude of about 39 miles some 55 miles downrange.